# Setting HTML Values through an separate js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing an web application in which the labels and keywords change according to different customers .

Consider i am having an html page :

```
<div>
  <p id="name"> Google </p>
  <p id="type"> Software </p>
  <p id="region"> California </p>
</div>
```

Now i want to change the values of everything as Facebook , Social Media , UK .

There is an straight forward method of changing it as

```
$("#name").text("Facebook"); and so on
```

But i don't want to do like this :

I want to do some template language like django does .

```
<div>
  <p id="name"> {{ name }} </p>
</div>
```

and i will pass value for name from json or js depending on requirement .

So, My question is there any plugin in jquery or bootstrap to achieve this type of need .???

Comment: You mean like angular, ember, backbone, underscore, or handlebars?

Comment: i am not much exposed to plugins and framework over jquery .. so i need suggestions to try on !

Comment: Google for 'javascript template engine' and you will find what you need, e.g.: https://github.com/trix/nano

Comment: Use Angular Js. I think it is best to fit your requirement

Comment: @karaokyo Handlebars !! yes something like this i am looking for . !

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <p id="name"> Google </p>
  <p id="type"> Software </p>
  <p id="region"> California </p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
obj = '{"name": "Facebook","type":"Social Media","region":"UK"}';
$.each($.parseJSON(obj), function(key,value){
    $("#"+key).text(value);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d4ty5kp8/)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can achieve this by using `jqtemplates`.
[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/farhansarkar/xd6a5q47/)

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="jqTemplate"> 
  <div>
    <p>${name}</p>
    <p>${type}</p>
    <p>${region}</p>
  </div> 
 </script> 
 <div id="myDiv"><div>

var json = {
    "name": "Google",
    "type": "Software",
    "region": "California"
};

$( "#jqTemplate" ).tmpl(json).appendTo("#myDiv");
```